# Google App Script function for dates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script that sends an email notification when a certain rule has resulted true/false.

Phase 1 : In my example I'm looking to send an Email 2 days before a "Task" is going to end

Phase 2 : I want to make an event In calendar for that 'task' as soon as it reaches that time frame as well. ( here I don't know what to do)

Iv managed to make this code, with the help of some tuts online, that sends the email to me, but this was accomplished with using numbers and I'm looking to use DATES so the difference between dates will give the result. any Idea how can I do this ?

```html
//Script that sends mail to your Gmail if certain amount is greater or less 
//than the amount you specify

function myFunction() {
  
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getRange(2, 1).getValue(); // getRange - Change to your cell
  var cell2 = ss.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  
  if(cell2-cell< 2){
   
    MailApp.sendEmail("yourEmail@gmail.com", "Hooray", "2 Days left bro")
    
  } 
  
  
}
```

google sheet - [SpreadSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xWfALrQ2w0OSFnhr_tKFJq0YaOgkoRY91nyN6uetQuw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below script...

```
function dateDiff() { 
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();        // getRange - Change to your cell

  for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++){ //start from 1, in order to skip the header
     var cell1 =  data[i][0];
     var cell2 =  data[i][1];
     cell1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
     cell2.setHours(0,0,0,0);

     var timeDiff = Math.abs(cell2.getTime() - cell1.getTime());
     var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

     if(diffDays<=2){
         MailApp.sendEmail("yourEmail@gmail.com", "Hooray", "2 Days left bro")
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: You are a magician man thank you so much thank you :)
I would appreciate if you can reference me to the things you have just done. and what do I need to do in order to apply this to the whole length off the columns / certain range?

Comment: @osherez, I have modified the script to loop thru the range

Comment: Thank you so match for your help Im speechless my friend. just for my knowledge I know its a big subject, but why did you use this lines? I know that what makes it happen, but I couldn't understand it :( 

"setHours(0,0,0,0)"
"Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)"

and again much appreciation keep it up,